# Xamarin virtual keyboard overlaps search component

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, keyboard

In my Xamarin project I have a listview with a search box on the bottom. When I go to type in a search value the virtual keyboard overlaps the search box?

> I tried to use Content.layout but I can't match the keyboard and search together Is there a way to fix this do I use a popup control?

```
   void InputFocused(object sender, EventArgs args){
        Content.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0,-360, Content.Bounds.Width, Content.Bounds.Height));
    }

    void InputUnfocused(object sender, EventArgs args){
        Content.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0,0, Content.Bounds.Width, Content.Bounds.Height));
    }
```

[image: Default listview]

[image: Enter Search Text]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXNIF.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ios , you can use this plugin, add to your ios project.

https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

For android, try to add the following code in App.xaml， new App()

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

If you still have this issue, please provide mode code here, I will try to reproduce your issue at my side.